# How to output a list of window titles in a console window?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Is there a way to output a list of running window titles to the command window?

I know that it's possible to filter based on window title using `tasklist /FI`. But is it possible to display a column of all window titles?

`TaskList` will provide the image name, but I'm looking for the name as it appears in the task manager under the applications tab.

Comment: What's provoking the question?

Comment: Do you want the window titles alone?  Not the process names?

Answer (score 7):

Create a batch called Windows-Open.cmd
and put the follwing command inside:

```
TASKLIST /v /fo list |find /i "window title" |find /v "N/A"
```

There are a few refinements we can yet do...
but for me its enough,,, simple,,, lean &% mean...

- you can easy derive from there, for example: Windows-noTitle.cmd
  etc. etc.

Stay good...

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this?

```
for /f "tokens=3,*" %a in ('tasklist /fo list /v ^| find "Window Title"') do @if not "%a"=="N/A" echo %a %b
```

Comment: Was just wondering why it didn't work in a terminal. Read 'bash' instead of 'batch' :)

Answer (score 1):

The command posted by [Ir Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2831951/ir-relevant) is good. But it must be adapted according to version and language of Windows.

For example the command for execution in a command prompt window on a German Windows XP is:

```
for /f "tokens=2,*" %a in ('tasklist.exe /fo list /v ^| find.exe "Fenstertitel:"') do @if not "%a %b"=="Nicht verfügbar" echo %a %b
```

And for usage in a batch file each `%` must be duplicated:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2,*" %%a in ('tasklist.exe /fo list /v ^| find.exe "Fenstertitel:"') do @if not "%%a %%b"=="Nicht verfügbar" echo %%a %%b
```

**Attention!**
German umlaut `ü` must be an OEM encoded `ü` with decimal code value 129 in the batch file instead of an ANSI encoded `ü` with decimal code value 252.